# Adding Teams messaging extension to an existing Graph Api project

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a Teams application with AspNetCore and React with typescript.
I would like to add the messaging extension functionality to my app. I have tested the available samples for Action based Messaging extension from here - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action

I could run this sample and successfully connect to the bot I created in my Azure resource group.

Since I already have a Teams project created, I want to know if I can just add the code that makes the messaging extension work from this sample or do I need to have a separate project just for running the bot and messaging extension?

**Note**- I do not have a Bot implementation in my original project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to combine them into the same project, you just need to make sure the endpoints all work correctly. The bot has, by convention, an endpoint at something like "/api/messages", but this is just a convention - you can use that or anything else you like, as long as you configure it properly in the Azure Bot registration so it knows what endpoint is for your bot, compared to the rest of the ASP.Net project.

Comment: I have the sample code as reference, where we add the BotID and Secret in the appsettings.json, however I couldn't figure out where are they using these values in the code. I have added the BotController and TeamsActivityHandler in my project but want to understand from where are the BotID and Secret are used while the project is running.

Comment: This is handled internally inside a class called the `BotFrameworkHttpAdapter`, where it will by default try to read the required values from your config file. See here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/integration/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core/BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.cs

Comment: I have added the BoController and the Bot code in the respective controllers and services in my project. Howeverl apart from these what other changes do I have to add my my project?. 
One thing I have noticed is that we are adding the IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter and IBot in the startup. Do i need to add that too in my code.

Comment: yes, absolutely you do - that's how they get 'activated', so to speak. Out of the box, the project is using Dependency Injection. It's not required for bot building per se, but it's just good development practice, that's why the sample / starter kits use it. Google the topic for more if it's not something you're familar with.